# .htaccess HTTPS to HTTP Not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect visits to https://www.domain.co.uk to http://www.domain.co.uk. I have researched this, but have come to a dead end.

Many people including people here, on SO suggest to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is my entire .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried putting the https rewrite code above, below and within the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`. But had no luck.

I know the .htaccess is being read, as I can make it return a 500 internal server error when using random letters.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Anubhava found out my server isn't listening for port 443 as my VirtualHost has no entry for it.

Here's that section of my httpd.conf

[image]

Comment: Do you have some CMS/PHP framework (e.g. WP) running?

Comment: Have you tried using `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443` instead? Is the site behind a load balancer at all?

Comment: Hi @anubhava I have WordPress running, but I do not believe this is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jon I have just tried that, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is WP then in your `permalink settings change` your site's URL to `http://domain.com` which seems to be `https://domain.com` at present. WP forces that URL if you're using a different one.

Your full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, my WP address and site address are both already set to http://www.domain.co.uk

Comment: Hmm strange, I provided your full .htaccess. Update it and try in a different browser. If it still doesn't work then run in Chrome developer tool and see what Net tab shows you.

Comment: No luck with that. I have even tried from my phone (over cellular) and though a proxy, still no luck. Net tab doesn't provide any debug info at all.

Comment: Net tab doesn't show any debug info. It shows http status codes like 200, 302, 301 etc. I just wanted to know what are those and how many are those. If you can share your actual URL I can also check it.

Comment: One GET success - text/html - data:text/html,chro… Nothing other than that. I think that's the UI for the chrome "This webpage is not available" page. It's https://www.essexghosthunters.co.uk :)

Comment: Ok figured out that your Apache isn't even listening on 443 for `https://www.essexghosthunters.co.uk/` check your `VirtualHost` entry for HTTPS

Comment: Oh right, thanks for digging around at it. So how would I go about that? Image of my httpd.conf is above. :)

Comment: I only see .htaccess code in the question. You will need to create a `VirrualHost` entry for HTTPS as well. Just search on Google you will get tons of helpful results.

Comment: As you can see you only have `VirtualHost` entry for port 80 not for 443

Comment: @anubhava, I checked your code. It is working on desktop browser but not working on mobile browser.

Comment: You have some local config issue because my rules are browser agnostic.